# creating a merge sort that accepts linkedlist as an input

Tags: c++

Here is some of my code

```
listnode *mergesort(struct listnode *list){
    struct listnode *L, *R, *head;
    int i = 0;
    head = list;
    while (list->next != NULL){
        if (i%2 == 0){              //it splits the linkedlist into 2 segments
                                    //it adds the elements in the linked list                                        
                                    // alternatively.
                                    //to a linked list R & L
            L=list->next;
            list->next = L->next;
            i=i+1;
        }
        else{
            R= list->next;
            list->next = R->next;
            i=i+1;
        }
        list = list->next;

    }
    MergeLists(mergesort(L),mergesort(R));
}
```

I keep getting segmentation faults and can't figure out what the problem is.

Comment: How about running under a debugger? You should be able to figure out the cause pretty quickly.

Comment: Try compiling with debug info (`-g` for gcc/clang), then use `catchsegv`, `valgrind`, and or `gdb` to find where the fault occurs.

Comment: thanks but does the code look right to you ?

Comment: Well, what does `MergeLists` do?

Comment: MergeLists is a function that takes two linkedlist and merge them based on values in each list. basically it compares the values in each list sort it in ascending order and merge the two list into one list

Comment: Sorry, I kinda meant 'how do you know it isn't breaking as well'. But to be brutally honest, no, your code does not look right. Think about what value R will have the first time you pass it recursively.

Comment: I 100% trust the MergeLists function i want R to point to the value of the linkedlist when it goes to else case(meaning 2, 4, 6, 8 etc values of the linkedlist) and i'm not sure if i'm doing it right.

Comment: OK, quick question before I write an answer - can we change the signature to mergesort (like, is it okay if I give it another argument)?

Comment: mergesort takes only one argument and that argument is linkedlist; so u can change my argument name but you cant change its type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, what your 'counting' is doing is moving `left` by one when the count is even, and doing the same to `right` when the count is odd. Not to mention that `left` and `right` are uninitialised if there is only one item in the list, and the last line of the loop could cause you to dereference a null.

Secondly, you need some way to mark off the end of the `left` list or else your mergesort will do the same thing over and over again until you overflow the stack.

We can do that by setting the last pointer in the left half to be NULL. Bear in mind that MergeLists will have to fix all that up to make one nice list again.

Try something like this:

```
listnode *mergesort(listnode *list) {
  listnode *left = list, *right = list, *prev, *end = list;

  if (list == 0) { return list; }

  // move right once for every two we move end, so that we divide the middle
  while (end != 0) {
    end = end->next;
    prev = right; // keep track of the node before the start of right
    right = right->next;

    if (end != 0) {
      end = end->next;
    }
  }


  if (left->next == right) {
    // TODO swap items if necessary
    return left;
  }

  prev->next = 0; // split the list
  left = mergesort(left);
  right = mergesort(right);
  // TODO join left and right by calling MergeLists or whatever
  return left;
}
```

Diagram of pointers at work:

```
prev->next = 0 removes -----|
                            v
list  -> [1] -> [2] -> [3] -> [4] -> [5] -> [6]
left  ----^                    ^
right -------------------------|
```

Comment: Thanks but where in your code are pointing to the other half of the linkedlist (left) ?

Comment: left points to the start of one half and right points to the start of the other half

Comment: @user4581941 See the diagram

Comment: oh! okay; now i have seen your logic. So what does this conditional statement do:  "if (left->next == right) {
    // TODO swap items if necessary
    return left;
  }"  or can u demonstrate it in a diagram that is if i were to use it how it would look like

Comment: Ok, I just fixed a couple of minor errors I let sneak in (right started set to NULL, prev->next in an inefficient place).

Comment: What the code you are asking about does is say "if the thing just after left is right, then there can only be one or two nodes in this list". The TODO says: If there are two, we can swap them directly to make a sorted sublist. If there is one, it is already a sorted sublist.

Comment: If you want to let MergeLists do all the swapping/inserting, then move `prev->next = 0; // split the list` to just before `if (left->next == right) {`, then rewrite the check as `if (left->next == 0 && right == 0)`, as it will only catch the one item case and the two item case with get MergeLists called on it.

Comment: @user4581941 If you would like, I can make a chat room so we can talk about this more.

Comment: Then what breaks the list ?

Comment: `prev->next = 0;` prev is the node before right (so if there are only two items, prev is left), so setting it's next pointer puts an end on the left half of the list.

Comment: according to the room, i have to have 20 reputation inorder to chat in the room

Comment: Ugh, that's super annoying. I'll fix that right now.

Comment: @user4581941 Looks like I can't, because the write access override (which is supposed to ignore rep) doesn't (because your rep is < 20... how's that for frustrating and ridiculous). I guess we just continue as best we can here then

Comment: oh yeah, do u have private exchange medium so that i can send you my final stuff for you to critique or see better ways of improving it

Answer (score 0):

Two things I noticed:
1. int i = 0; means i will always be even. Is 'i' meant to be the value in the list node?
2. return MergeLists(L,R); is inside the while statement thus the loop will exit.

Comment: Thanks, I have just fixed the MergeLists(L,R) in the while loop but int i = 0 initializes " i " so that i can add elements of the linkedlist alternatively.  "i" has no link with the node, "i" is just a switch from 0 to 1; if its 0 add the element to L otherwise add it to R